# FB.ui send invoked from JavaScript SDK doesn't work on iPad

Tags: facebook, ipad, safari, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've trying to get the following to work on iPad. Works fine in all desktop browsers but fail on iPad with `API Error Code 3, Unknown method. This method isn't supported by this display type`.

```
FB.ui({
  method:'send',
  to:anyUserId,
  link: anyLink,
  name: anyName,
  display: 'popup',
  show_error: true
});
```

I've reported [a bug to Facebook issue tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/137149103080662). Still because I can't find anything in existing bugs or in Google I suspect that it can be my mistake. If you have any clues, it will be great to get your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience with android it seems like the send dialog is not supported for the mobile world (what fb calls touch display).

You should be able to open the dialog in some sort of web view using the url showed in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/):

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=APP_ID&
  name=LINK_NAME&
  link=LINK_URL&
  redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
```

Comment: I have to mention that one should use `encodeURIComponent` when building this URL. Other than that it seems to work. Will use it as a fallback. Thanks.

Comment: Still, I'll wait a bit with accepting this as a best solution in case there's a way to get "normal" dialogs on iPad.

Comment: Accepted. Adding `display=popup` makes it suitable for mobile. So overall it works just fine now. Still it's strange that Facebook JavaScript SDK doesn't do the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "Facebook JavaScript SDK doesn't do the same"?

Comment: I meant Facebook JavaScript SDK is forming very different link compared to what provided by you and it doesn't work.

Comment: For future reference, at the present date this was not working at least in Android. "This dialog cannot be displayed on this device." and Facebook states: "This dialog can be used with the JavaScript SDK and by performing a full redirect to a URL. It is not supported on mobile devices."